# How can I change the font beyond the ones in options in Git Bash?

Tags: git-bash

I want to use the [Hack](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts/Hack#linux) [Nerd Font](https://www.nerdfonts.com/#features) for [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) on Windows.
I have the font installed, but it doesn't appear in options. If I run the command `mintty -o Font="Hack NF"`, it does work in a new [mintty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mintty) window, but if I provide the `-o Font` option to *git-bash.exe* itself, it doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the issue tracker at [mintty](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty/issues/29) they only look at fonts that are flagged as monospace.

I found an [issue against Roboto Mono](https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/225) asking for the 'isFixedPitch' flag to be set for the font, so it is not an uncommon problem.

You can specify the font manually in the `.minttyrc` file located in your home directory.

For example I tried this and it works.

```
FontHeight=16
Font=Hack Nerd Font
```